# How to get one row per group in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data:

```
customerid addressid
939          936
939          35485
1915         2224
1915         34236
6005         7012
6005         27914
```

given by this query:

```
select customerid ,addressid
from addresses
where .....
```

I want the query to return only one address per customer, I don't care which address it will be.
So the desiered output can be:

```
addressid
936
2224
7012
```

or

```
addressid
936
34236
7012
```

etc..

I tried to do:

```
select DISTINCT customerid ,addressid
from addresses
where .....
```

but it did nothing... I thought of doing `GROUP BY customerid` but then I'm losing the `addressid`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care which addressid it is, this is a simple `group by`:

```
select customerid, max(addressid) as addressid
from addresses
group by customerid
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by `customerid` and since it can be any address use a aggegation function like `max()` get the hghest

```
select customerid, max(addressid)
from addresses
group by customerid
```